# How to route to Cloudfront+s3 and rest to ALB in Route53?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-ecs, amazon-alb

The project has a domain name `foobar.com` pointing to a legacy system, hosting and serving mainly static files. The project got more complex over time and in AWS ALB certain `/routes` are pointed to particularly isolated micro-applications (for example, a nodejs api service, a php service like a cms, etc); all that deployed through AWS ECS. But today, I'd like to deploy a project that is just static files to s3+cloudfront (to take the CDN advantages and lower pricing) but use that same `foobar.com` + ALB and route `/foobar` path to the s3+cloudfront location. I haven't found a solution yet, and I'm not sure if this is possible to setup? What options exist there to solve my use case? So, the current state is that the main domain name is pointing to A record `ALIAS dualstack-alb`.

Cloudfront has the optional CNAME, but as mentioned above the domain name `foobar.com` is pointing to the legacy project container and only certain `/routes` elsewhere.

When a new distribution is created I get a `foobar.cloudfront.net` domain that I can use to access the deployed static files. But obviously that's not what I want and I'd like to use the main domain name `foobar.com` and when the `/routeX` is requested to point or serve the `foobar.cloudfront.net`. This is:

```
foobar.com > shows the legacy project, in ec2 container 1
foobar.com/cms > shows the cms project, in ec2 container 2
foobar.com/myNewProject/ > should show the X project, in s3
```

The following diagram demonstrates how this works or should work:

[image]

After the research I did so far, it seems that I have to point the main domain name A record to Cloudfront instead of having the A record pointing to ALB `ALIAS dualstack.xxxxxxs-alb-xxxxx` and have cloudfront `/route` point to s3. And everything else to the `ALB`. That's where my question comes from!

I'm just spying at the moment and can't seem to find how to set `/route` to s3 and everything else to the `alb` though! I can see the CNAME option in cloudfront but no route rules or anything like it.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, looking at the documentation I found a solution!

First, we need to point the DNS A record to Cloudfront, so that Cloudfront process happens before anything else.

Second, we need to identify the content origin as described here (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesDomainName).

Third, we specify the path patterns (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesPathPattern) to point to the content origin.